# Matplotlib- Colour scheme

Tags: matplotlib

I have a (256,256) numpy array. Each element has a value of 1 or 2 or 3.
I would like to plot this array as an image by:`plt.plot(A)'
What I would like to do is assigning this colour scheme to every element;
1: red, 2:blue and 3: gray.

I have no idea how I can do that, Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`plt.imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) and a [`ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html). The example below uses yellow instead of gray to see the different colors a bit better ('lightgray' probably looks better than 'gray').

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 14))
A = (gaussian_filter(np.random.randn(256, 256), 20) * 200).astype(int) % 3 + 1
cmap = ListedColormap(['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'yellow'])
plt.imshow(A, origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=np.linspace(1, 3, 7)[1::2])
cbar.set_ticklabels([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Wow, awesome, worked...one more question. how can I plot the image with bigger size? really appreciate it

Comment: You could start the code setting a size, e.g. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 15))`. Anyway, individual cells will be hard to see without zooming.